# MD analysis using Python

Tags: python, simulation, orientation, protein-database, mdanalysis

I am trying to run this command:

`python3 traj_orientation-group.py -g fnIII-9_ps20_Nchain6_T298_nw.gro -x fnIII-9_ps20_Nchain6_T298_nw.xtc -o fnIII-9_ps20_Nchain6_run1.phrsn-orientation --protein_res_start 1 --protein_res_stop 89 –group 51 52 53 54 55`

This is for MD analysis. I got this following error below:

`usage: traj_orientation-group.py [-h] [-g GROFILE] [-x XTCFILE] [-o OUTFILE] [--protein_res_start PROTEIN_RES_START] [--protein_res_stop PROTEIN_RES_STOP] [--group GROUP [GROUP ...]] traj_orientation-group.py: error: unrecognized arguments: –group 51 52 53 54 55`

How can I resolve this?

Comment: For more context, see the mailing list thread https://groups.google.com/g/mdnalysis-discussion/c/J8oJ0M9Rjb4/m/vHsPjXC1DQAJ

Comment: The solution here was to use `--group` instead of `-group`, so this question can be closed as "Typo".

Answer (score 1):

You are providing an argument `–group 51 52 53 54 55`
and it seems that the only option in the source script is `--group` (so a double dash is needed)

I will also mention that `-g` and `--group` are equivalent and you already provided some arguments to `-g` here -> `-g fnIII-9_ps20_Nchain6_T298_nw.gro`

Comment: Hi, it worked with --group. Thanks a lot

Comment: please accept the best answer if it worked :)